# WooCommerce Subscription

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, woocommerce-subscriptions

Say I have 10 products and want to offer them in a subscription.

```
Product 1 ($10) - 1st Month
Product 2 ($15) - 2nd Month
Product 3 ($20) - 3rd Month
.
.
.
.
So on...
```

As you can see, the price is different per month. Is that possible in WooCommerce? (Subscribed to a product/Plan but pays varying amount each month)

I can't find anything in the WooCommerce docs that discusses this scenario.

Thanks.

Comment: This hook looks interesting woocommerce_scheduled_subscription_payment, found it in the action reference:  https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/subscriptions/develop/action-reference/ and here the filter reference: https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/subscriptions/develop/filter-reference/

Answer (score 1):

You can set subscription price as 0 and then manually add products for each month. This way the monthly price wuld be the product price only. You can also add shipping cost or any other fee you want to charge.
Instructions on how you can do this are here : https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/subscriptions/add-or-modify-a-subscription/
To automate, you can use the "Subscription Product" as product type.
(Subscription Product is an extention to the default product types in WooCommerce)